# Strange error while using instanceof

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   AjaxCalls = new AjaxCalls();
   console.log(AjaxCalls);
   if (AjaxCalls instanceof AjaxCalls) console.log("TEST");
});
```

When I run this code I get the following output:

```
 Object { cache: Object, cacheMaxSize: 2097152, cacheOrder: Array[0], cacheSize: 0, selfLog: Array[0], debug: true, calls: Object }
 TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand AjaxCalls
```

Why do I get this error message, when AjaxCalls is clearly a function?

*I am using the latest version of Firefox*

Comment: the function or the result of calling it?  Why don't you rename the result of calling it:  `var ajaxCallsInstance = new AjaxCalls();`.  That might parse better.

Comment: AjaxCalls is not resolved to a function anymore, its a object. The browser have two kinds of "AjaxCalls" the latest is more meaningfull and used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AjaxCalls` object is overriding by a variable `AjaxCalls`. The browser throws you the correct error. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var ajax_calls = new AjaxCalls();
   console.log(ajax_calls);
   if (ajax_calls instanceof AjaxCalls) console.log("TEST");
});
```

Comment: Note: by not using `var`, `ajax_calls` (or OP's `AjaxCalls`) is hoisted to the global scope (and is bad practice)

Comment: Yeah, I only edit the variable name, but make the `window` object dirty is bad practice as you said.